# Dynamically create filename in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have been asked a couple times to change the file name dynamically in SSRS 2008.  Example: ReportName_201101.RDL.  The 201101 represents the execution date.  Can this be accomplished in SSRS 2008?

Answer (score 7):

If you mean the filename when you export the report and also happen to be pulling it from the ASP.NET ReportViewer, you can set the name through the DisplayName property.

```
ReportViewerControl.ServerReport.DisplayName = "ReportName_201101";
```

or (if `ProcessingMode` is Local):

```
ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.DisplayName = "ReportName_201101";
```

For pretty much all other cases, Alison is right.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [MS Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/525193/ssrs-2008-report-delivery-via-email-needs-filename-option-for-attachment) open for this. It only has a few votes, so head over there and upvote it...

Answer (score 2):

Another work around, is to rename the report before it runs automatically. This is a diamond in the rough. This may only work for reports that are subscriptions and not ones that users link back to. 
Create a table on the ReportServer database that contains a listing of all reports that you want to rename before they execute. 
Table Report_Rename_Listing
    RenameID int 
    ItemID uniqueidentifier
    OriginalReportName nvarchar(350)
    DateType nvarchar(75)
    Format int
    DatePlusMinus real
Create a stored procedure on the same server that goes out and changes all the reports in the above table.

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[RenameReports]
AS
SET NOCOUNT OFF ; 
  Update dbo.Catalog 
    Set Name = ISNULL(( Select OriginalReportName + '_' + 
               dbo.func_SetupRenameOfReports(DateType, Format, DatePlusMinus)
      From dbo.DDC_Report_Rename r
      Where r.ItemID = c.ItemID), Name)  
  From dbo.Catalog c
return (0)
```

Create a scalar function on same server that figures out just how you want to rename the report.

```
Create Function [dbo].[func_SetupRenameOfReports]
( @DateType nvarchar(75), @Format int, @PlusMinus real  )
RETURNS nvarchar(75)
AS
BEGIN
  Declare @FirstMonth datetime, @LastMonth datetime
  Declare @OutputFormat nvarchar(75)

  Set @FirstMonth = CONVERT(datetime, Convert(varchar(2), DateAdd(mm, @PlusMinus, GetDate()), 103) + '/1/' + CONVERT(varchar(4), DateAdd(mm, @PlusMinus, GetDate()), 102))
  Set @LastMonth = DATEADD(dd, -1, DateAdd(mm, 1, @FirstMonth))

  Set @OutputFormat = 
    Case When @DateType = 'CurrentDate' Then Convert(varchar(75), DateAdd(dd, @PlusMinus, GetDate()), @Format)
         When @DateType = 'CurrentDayName' Then CONVERT(varchar(75), DateName(dw, DateAdd(dd, @PlusMinus, GetDate())))
         When @DateType = 'CurrentMonthName' Then CONVERT(varchar(75), DateName(mm, DateAdd(mm, @PlusMinus, GetDate())))
         When @DateType = 'CurrentYear' Then CONVERT(varchar(75), DateAdd(yy, @PlusMinus, GetDate()))
         When @DateType = 'CurrentBeginEndMonth' Then CONVERT(varchar(10), @FirstMonth, @Format) + '-' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @LastMonth, @Format)
    End

  If @OutputFormat IS null 
    Begin 
      Set @OutputFormat = ''
    End
 Return @OutputFormat

END
```

Then setup this up to have the stored procedure automatically run daily on your server. I have it run just after midnight every day.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, it is not possible.  It is another one of those features that is missing from SSRS that developers have been asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a correction to the above stored procedure so that it actual works.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ddc_RenameReports]

AS
SET NOCOUNT OFF ; 

  Update dbo.Catalog 
    Set Name = ISNULL((Select OriginalReportName + '_' + 
               dbo.func_SetupRenameOfReports(DateType, Format, DatePlusMinus)
      From dbo.DDC_Report_Rename r
      Where r.ItemID = c.ItemID And r.Active = 1), Name) 
  From dbo.Catalog c
  Update c
    Set c.Path = ISNULL((Select c2.Path + '/' + OriginalReportName + '_' + 
               dbo.func_SetupRenameOfReports(DateType, Format, DatePlusMinus)
          From dbo.DDC_Report_Rename r2
          Where r2.ItemID = c.ItemID AND r2.Active = 1), c.Path)       
  From dbo.Catalog c
    inner join dbo.Catalog c2 on c2.ItemID = c.ParentID 
return (0)
```