# SSRS - Dynamic Export File Name

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm creating a report in SSRS 2008 R2. I have a drop down from which the use user can select an organization against which the report is generated.

What I need is, When I click the Export icon, Instead of the File name automatically given as the Report file name (ie: If RDL  name is, report.rdl then the file name will be, report) I need it to be the name of the organization which the user selected from the Dropdown.

I'm storing the value from the drop down to a variable, so I need to export file name as same as the value stored in the Variable

Comment: This does not appear to be possible in the SSRS application, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725414/dynamically-create-filename-in-ssrs-2008.  You could maybe set a data driven-subscription to export all of them one by one and name them that way, but it would be schedule and not user driven.